# Why are my cards blank?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I've created a Soitaire game in java, but when I compile the application (without errors) for some reason the cards end up empty.

Here are parts of the code containing graphics.

**In Card.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Card extends JPanel {
  /**
 * defines all values of rank a card can achieve
 */
public enum Rank {
    Ace, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King
}

/**
 * defines all values of color a card can achieve
 */
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES
}

private Rank cardRank; ///< will store the rank of our card
private Suit cardColor; ///< will store the color of our card
private boolean faceUp; ///< determines which side the card is facing
private Point location; ///< location of our card on board, has to be stored individually
private Point where; ///< location of Card to others

/// @2DD coordinates
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;

/// offsets for cards
private final int x_offset = 10;
private final int y_offset = 20;
private final int new_x_offset = x_offset + (CARD_WIDTH - 30);
/// constants for card graphical view
final static public int CARD_WIDTH = 100;
final static public int CARD_HEIGHT = 150;
final static public int ANGLE = 25;

  /**
     *  Defines a sample card object that specifies it's parameters
     *
     * @param defRank - pre-defined rank
     * @param defColor - pre-defined color
     */
    public Card(Rank defRank, Suit defColor){
        cardRank = defRank;
        cardColor = defColor;
        faceUp = false;
        location = new Point();
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        location.x = x;
        location.y = y;
        where = new Point();
    }



/*  Function for drawing out a card Color
 *
 * @param defColor - defines which card color (symbol we want)
 * @param defColorCode - defines which actual color code should be used for the symbol
 */
private void drawSuit(Graphics2D g, String defColor, Color defColorCode)
{
    g.setColor(defColorCode);
    g.drawString(defColor, location.x + x_offset, location.y + y_offset);
    g.drawString(defColor, location.x + x_offset, location.y + CARD_HEIGHT - 5);
}

/**
 *  similar as color, but instead of symbol we draw the value
 * @see drawColor for more info
 */
private void drawRank(Graphics2D g, String defRank){
    g.drawString(defRank, location.x + new_x_offset, location.y + y_offset);
    g.drawString(defRank, location.x + new_x_offset, location.y + y_offset + CARD_HEIGHT - 25);
}

/**
     *  basically acts as a main for the Card. Creates  card with graphical display
     *
     * @param g2d - utilizes java graphic library to draw compotents of our defined functions
     */
    public void createCard(Graphics g2d){
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2d; ///< konvertujeme do 2d grafiky
        RoundRectangle2D rect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(location.x, location.y, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, ANGLE, ANGLE);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fill(rect);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.draw(rect);

        if (faceUp == true){
            switch(cardColor){
                case HEARTS:
                    drawSuit(g, "Hearts", Color.RED);
                    break;
                case DIAMONDS:
                    drawSuit(g, "Diamonds", Color.RED);
                    break;
                case CLUBS:
                    drawSuit(g, "Clubs", Color.BLACK);
                    break;
                case SPADES:
                    drawSuit(g, "Spades", Color.BLACK);
                    break;
            }

            int new_x_offset = x_offset + (CARD_WIDTH - 30);
            switch (cardRank){
                case Ace:
                    drawRank(g, "Ace (A)");
                    break;
                case Two:
                    drawRank(g, "Two (2)");
                    break;
                case Three:
                    drawRank(g, "Three (3)");
                    break;
                case Four:
                    drawRank(g, "Four (4)");
                    break;
                case Six:
                    drawRank(g, "Six (5)");
                    break;
                case Five:
                    drawRank(g, "Five (6)");
                    break;
                case Seven:
                    drawRank(g, "Seven (7)");
                    break;
                case Eight:
                    drawRank(g, "Eight (8)");
                    break;
                case Nine:
                    drawRank(g, "Nine (9)");
                    break;
                case Ten:
                    drawRank(g, "Ten (10)");
                    break;
                case Jack:
                    drawRank(g, "Jack (J)");
                    break;
                case Queen:
                    drawRank(g, "Queen (Q)");
                    break;
                case King:
                    drawRank(g, "King (K)");
                    break;
            }
        } // end of if

        else { ///< ked je karta otocena spodkom
            RoundRectangle2D rect2D = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(location.x, location.y, CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, ANGLE, ANGLE);
            g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g.fill(rect2D);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.draw(rect2D);
        } // end of else
    } // end of function


} // end of file (class Card.java)
```

**In CardStack.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
/**
  * We decided to fuse CardDeck with CardStack. CardDeck can contain multiple card stacks
  *
  * @param isDeck - a boolean that checks if we want a deck or only a stack. Deck contains all cards
  */
public CardStack(boolean isDeck) {
    deck = new Stack<Card>();
    this.setLayout(null);
    if(isDeck) {
        for (Card.Suit suit : Card.Suit.values()) {
            for (Card.Rank rank : Card.Rank.values()) {
                deck.push(new Card(rank, suit));
            }
        }
    } else
        playStack = true;
}


/**
      * Paints the entire component, similar to card
      *
      * @see Card
      * @param g - utilizes Graohic library.
      */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (playStack) {
            removeAll();
            ListIterator<Card> iter = deck.listIterator();
            Point prev = new Point(); /// positioning relative to the container
            Point prevWhereAmI = new Point();/// abs positioning on the board
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                Card c = iter.next();
                //// this origin is point(0,0) inside the cardstack container
                prev = new Point();/// c.getXY(); /// starting deck pos
                add(Solitaire.moveCard(c, prev.x, prev.y));
                /// setting x & y position
                c.setWhere(getXY());
                prevWhereAmI = getXY();
            } else {
                removeAll();
            }

            for (; iter.hasNext(); ) {
                Card c = iter.next();
                c.setXY(new Point(prev.x, prev.y + SPREAD));
                add(Solitaire.moveCard(c, prev.x, prev.y + SPREAD));
                prev = c.getXY();
                /// setting x & y position
                c.setWhere(new Point(prevWhereAmI.x, prevWhereAmI.y + SPREAD));
                prevWhereAmI = c.getWhere();
            }

        }
    }
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g, boolean isFinalStack)
{
    removeAll();
    if (!emptyStack())
    {
        add(Solitaire.moveCard(this.peekLast(), 1, 1));
    } else
    {
        /// draw back of card if empty
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        RoundRectangle2D rect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, Card.CARD_WIDTH, Card.CARD_HEIGHT,
                Card.ANGLE, Card.ANGLE);
        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2d.fill(rect);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.draw(rect);
    }

}
```

And finally the last part of the classes, **Solitaire.java** which basically ties it all together.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import src.ija.Card;
import src.ija.CardStack;

  /// GUI COMPONENTS (top level)
    private static final JFrame frame = new JFrame("IJA Klondike Solitaire");
    protected static final JPanel table = new JPanel();
    /// other components
    private static JEditorPane gameTitle = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
    private static JButton showRulesButton = new JButton("Show Rules");
    private static JButton newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
    private static JButton toggleTimerButton = new JButton("Pause Timer");
    private static JTextField scoreBox = new JTextField();/// displays the score
    private static JTextField timeBox = new JTextField();/// displays the time
    private static JTextField statusBox = new JTextField();/// status messages
    private static final Card newCardButton = new Card();/// reveal waste card

  private static void playNewGame()
    {
        deck = new CardStack(true); /// deal 52 cards
        deck.shuffle();
        table.removeAll();
        /// reset stacks if user starts a new game in the middle of one
        if (playCardStack != null && final_cards != null)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < NUM_PLAY_DECKS; x++)
            {
                while(!playCardStack[x].emptyStack()){
                    playCardStack[x].popStack();
                }
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < NUM_FINAL_DECKS; x++)
            {
                while(!final_cards[x].emptyStack()){
                    final_cards[x].popStack();
                }
            }
        }
        /// initialize & place final (foundation) decks/stacks
        final_cards = new CardStack[NUM_FINAL_DECKS];
        for (int x = 0; x < NUM_FINAL_DECKS; x++)
        {
            final_cards[x] = new CardStack(false, true);

            final_cards[x].setXY((FINAL_POS.x + (x * Card.CARD_WIDTH)) + 10, FINAL_POS.y, true);
            table.add(final_cards[x]);

        }
        /// place new card distribution button
        table.add(moveCard(newCardButton, DECK_POS.x, DECK_POS.y));
        /// initialize & place play (tableau) decks/stacks
        playCardStack = new CardStack[NUM_PLAY_DECKS];
        for (int x = 0; x < NUM_PLAY_DECKS; x++)
        {
            playCardStack[x] = new CardStack(false);
            playCardStack[x].setXY((DECK_POS.x + (x * (Card.CARD_WIDTH + 10))), PLAY_POS.y);

            table.add(playCardStack[x]);
        }

        /// Dealing new game
        for (int x = 0; x < NUM_PLAY_DECKS; x++)
        {
            int hld = 0;
            Card c = deck.popStack().turnFaceUp();
            playCardStack[x].putFirst(c);

            for (int y = x + 1; y < NUM_PLAY_DECKS; y++)
            {
                playCardStack[y].putFirst(c = deck.popStack());
            }
        }
        /// reset time
        time = 0;
        newGameButton.addActionListener(new NewGameListener());
        newGameButton.setBounds(0, TABLE_HEIGHT - 70, 120, 30);

        showRulesButton.addActionListener(new ShowRulesListener());
        showRulesButton.setBounds(120, TABLE_HEIGHT - 70, 120, 30);

        gameTitle.setText("<b>IJA Solitaire</b> <br>");
        gameTitle.setEditable(false);
        gameTitle.setOpaque(false);
        gameTitle.setBounds(245, 20, 100, 100);

        scoreBox.setBounds(240, TABLE_HEIGHT - 70, 120, 30);
        scoreBox.setText("Score: 0");
        scoreBox.setEditable(false);
        scoreBox.setOpaque(false);

        timeBox.setBounds(360, TABLE_HEIGHT - 70, 120, 30);
        timeBox.setText("Seconds: 0");
        timeBox.setEditable(false);
        timeBox.setOpaque(false);

        startTimer();

        toggleTimerButton.setBounds(480, TABLE_HEIGHT - 70, 125, 30);
        toggleTimerButton.addActionListener(new ToggleTimerListener());

        statusBox.setBounds(605, TABLE_HEIGHT - 70, 180, 30);
        statusBox.setEditable(false);
        statusBox.setOpaque(false);

        table.add(statusBox);
        table.add(toggleTimerButton);
        table.add(gameTitle);
        table.add(timeBox);
        table.add(newGameButton);
        table.add(showRulesButton);
        table.add(scoreBox);
        table.repaint();
    }

  public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Container contentPane;

        frame.setSize(TABLE_WIDTH, TABLE_HEIGHT);

        table.setLayout(null);
        table.setBackground(new Color(0, 180, 0));

        contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(table);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        playNewGame();

        table.addMouseListener(new CardMovementManager());
        table.addMouseMotionListener(new CardMovementManager());

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

I'm sorry for huge code dumps, but I genuinely do not know what's causing the issue. Here is the resulting game after I launch the app.

[image]
This is the resulting game. First I thought it's just that the Cards are always wasing in wrong direction, but even when I brute-forced faceUp to be true; they still looked like this.

Probably not the tidiest question of all time, but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Are `cardcolour` and `cardrank` properly set?

Comment: @NickA I've edited my post (added at top of the Card.java code). I believe they are (at least they should be), but sometimes you never know.

Comment: What about the CardStack creation code? You've only included its painting

Comment: @NickA yeah was actually half-way thriough my edit already, realising I should probably do the same with CardStack. Only function where I'd consider any messing up would be possible is in it's ver definiton, which has been included as well now.